# Do we need to run flush privileges after changing variable default_password_lifetime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

MySQL has a new variables in MySQL-5.7 which keeps the mysql user's password expiration details - after how many days the password expires for a particular user.

Detail of this variables :  [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_password_lifetime)

When we changed this variable, is it necessary to run flush privileges or the changes will take affect immediately for all the users having default expire policy ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

because default_password_lifetime is a global variables,which information stored in information_schema.GLOBAL_VARAIBLES,It's a memory engine table!

In mysql,the flush action cause the data in the buffer write back into disk,it's only necessary in MyISAM engine;however, the flush privileges clause is  reload the data from disk MyISAM file to memory about account & privileges related table.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it should not be necessary:

> [6.3.6 Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html)
>
> ...
>
> When a client successfully connects, the server determines whether the
>   account password is expired:
>
> - The server checks whether the password has been manually expired and, if so, restricts the session.
> - Otherwise, the server checks whether the password is past its lifetime according to the automatic password expiration policy. If so,
>     the server considers the password expired and restricts the session.
>
> ...

**IMPORTANT: The change take effect only for subsequent connections.**

Here an example:

```sql
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
Server version: 5.7.18

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.default_password_lifetime;
+------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.default_password_lifetime |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  0 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'johndoe'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '*6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4'
    -> PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

$ mysql -u johndoe -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 14
Server version: 5.7.18

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+-------------------+
| CURRENT_USER()    |
+-------------------+
| johndoe@localhost |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 5.7.18

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.default_password_lifetime := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.default_password_lifetime;
+------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.default_password_lifetime |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  1 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2010-01-01 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> \! date -s "2010-01-02 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"
Sat Jan 02 00:00:05 UTC 2010
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2010-01-02 00:00:06 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

$ mysql -u johndoe -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.7.18

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.
```

Other information of interest:

- [6.2.6 When Privilege Changes Take Effect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html).